Limit/Block Haproxy to access Web Server via IP Address
I would like to know how we can limit haproxy to access backend Web Server via IP address. Access should be granted via domain only.
I tried to use haproxy ACL, but it didn't worked. I am expecting it by using ACL but somehow i am unable to reach it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Basically you cannot deny access to a resource by IP, because this is how a connection is made to a server.
In other words you don't know if the client is calling http://192.0.2.1 or http://www.example.com.
But you can at HTTP level check the host header and deny hosts matching an IP address:
frontend foo
  bind 192.0.2.1:80
  mode http
  acl is_host_ip req.hdr(host) -m ip 0/0 ::/0
  http-request deny if is_host_ip
  ...

this will reject a request if a host header matches an IPv4 or IPv6 pattern.
